# Android Application Creating Two Launcher Icons instead of One

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher

I have a weird problem, where when installing the application I see two icons, one launches the application and the other says "App is not installed" when I click it.

I'm sure that I only have one `intent-filter` tag that contains

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

I even checked the merged final AndroidManifest.xml in the intermediaries folder, and I still don't see another `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

Here is my main AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.package">

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup">

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LauncherActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.VerificationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Verification" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MallActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".activity.StoreActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.EnclosedFragmentActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

    <provider
        android:name=".provider.MallBuddyProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.package"
        android:exported="false"
        android:syncable="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SearchActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".sync.AuthenticatorService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".sync.SyncService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
</application>
```

Comment: I sometimes experience this while testing apps on devices, device reboot usually removes the corrupted one

Comment: Thanks! The problem is solved after restarting the device, uninstalling the APK and then reinstall didn't solve the problem, it only was solved after restarting the device.
Can you please answer this question, so that I can upvote you and mark the question as solved with your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sometimes experience this while testing apps on devices, rebooting the device removes the corrupted one, solving the problem.

I don't know what causes this corrupt second launcher icon, though.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly this type of problem Occur when you have the below code more than once in activity tag.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Delete this lines from activity tag where it has occured twice.

Comment: @TimCastelijns it might be in his manifest file. This issue occurs when two activities in manifest file have the above code. and the question was edited later by adding manifest file content. So cannot predict.

Comment: "might be" ?  the manifest is in the question, and it has only one. OP even said he only has one

Comment: As @TimCastelijns said, I'm pretty sure that it only has one <intent-filter> with the above code, even the merged AndroidManifest.xml that is generated after building the project does only contain one <intent-filter> LAUNCHER category and MAIN action.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appeared to me after changing the manifest file only for one of my two build variants. I was refactoring activity names there, and forgot to change the second file.

After changing everything there too, this was fixed.